# Facebook Open Graph actions for a simple website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to use the "Share Dialog" to share a URL on peoples News Feed. The URL I am sharing is using a couple of custom Open Graph actions. We submitted the actions for review, but the submission is getting declined because we don't implement Facebook Login? [image]

The site is a simple marketing site, and we don't have any kind of login. Can we not use Open Graph actions without Facebook Login?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement Facebook login functionality. The message you received contains just the sample instructions (they used the example of the common app using Facebook login). In your case you should include rather something like:

1. Press the "Share" button (including screenshot of the page with the button)
2. Share the message (including screenshot of sharing box)
3. *Display message/other action after sharing (if applies)

Additionally you would need to brief how are you going to use the Open Graph actions that you are mentioning. And that would be enough.